# Short of testing an equation how can one tell if a value could be valid

Tags: algorithms

I'm working with an algorithm that given an integer in the inclusive range `1..54` outputs a different number in the same range with no values being duplicated, the specific equation is `mod(21 * i, 55)`, the equation `mod(43 * i, 55)` also fits the 'no-duplicates rule' and a total of 72 numbers in the exclusive range `0..100` also meets this requirement, the first part of my question is this, what is the relation (if any) between these specific numbers that determines whether or not they will meet this requirement, and second is there some potential significance (beyond preference) to why the number 21 was chosen initially?

The 72 numbers that meet this requirement are as follows:
`1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,23,24,26,27,28,29,31,32,34,36,37,38,39,41,42,43,46,47,48,49,51,52,53,54,56,57,58,59,61,62,63,64,67,68,69,71,72,73,74,76,78,79,81,82,83,84,86,87,89,91,92,93,94,96,97,98`

I know why `1` is on this list, as well as `54` but the remaining numbers appear to have no connection besides satisfying the requirement of the equation.

Comment: Briefly, $21$ and $55$ are coprime, so $21$ has an inverse $\mod {55}$, so if $21i\equiv 21j\pmod{55}$ then $i\equiv j \pmod{55}$.

Comment: @peterwhy I suppose that may explain why 21 was specifically chosen.

Comment: I mean all those $72$ candidates should be coprime with $55$. Why specifically $21$ or $43$, I am not sure yet.

Comment: having calculated all the valid values from the range previously checked, I am able to confirm that all 72 candidates are in fact coprime with 55. So the relation between the digits is that each is coprime with the mod. which then likely means that the choice of 21 over any other digit must simply be the original authors arbitrary choice.